Load multiple signers from multiple ledgers with safe-cli
I received a transaction sent on the incorrect blockchain, resulting in the funds being inaccessible at the moment. I'm trying to use the safe-cli tool to retrieve them. Our account is protected by a multisig setup. I've successfully added one Ledger device, but I'm having trouble adding another one to sign the transaction. Can you use more than one Ledger device with safe-cli to authorize a transaction in a multisig setup?

Have you followed all steps mentioned in our documentation, specifically regarding installation and/or use on Linux?
Best, Louis
